# Why oracle linux system's /var/log/cron timezone different from system date?

Tags: cron, timezone, logs

My Oracle Linux 6 system date prints:

```
$ date Sat Mar 18 08:05:10 PDT 2017
```

And `/var/log/cron` timestamp prints:

```
Mar 18 15:05:04
```

Why is it different, where can I make the change (is there any conf file), so that cron log prints the log in same timezone as system?

Comment: I guess time stamp is printed using UTC time zone, while `date` outputs a time in your current time zone.

Comment: Thanks @ddnomad Issue resolved. Did following: 1) /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
2)  /etc/init.d/crond restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by running the following:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart
/etc/init.d/crond restart
```

Comment: I was having similar issue. Thanks, this helped me.